# error:cannot convert 'const char*' to const string*

Tags: string, pointers, char

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 5; 
    double d = 0.5;
    const string *ps = "Hello Man";
    char *pc = "k";
    void *pv;

    pv = (void*)ps;
    cout << pv;

}
```

Code is above. I tried putting in "Hello Man" into ps and got the error mentioned in title.

I also got an error with the line "char *pc = "k"; The compiler said, "Forbids converting a string constant to char*. Last time nobody answered my question. I hope someone answers it this time. Thank you.